# Using WinRS to process a command on a remote machine

Tags: windows-server-2008, winrm

So I have machines:

Client machine: Windows 7 on domain A
Server machine: Windows 2008 R2 on domain B, after running `winrm quickconfig`

I'm using the following command as a test script:

`winrs /r:Servername /u:<domainA/ylogin> /p:<mypassword> ping 127.0.0.1`

However when I try that I get `WinRM cannot process the request. The following error occurred while using Kerberos authentication: The network path was not found.`.

When I try replacing the `Servername` with `<ipaddress>` I get a different error:

`Winrs error:The WinRM client cannot process the request. Default authentication may be used with an IP address under the following conditions: the transport is HTTPS or the destination is in the TrustedHosts list, and explicit credentials are provided. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in TrustedHosts list might not be authenticated. For more information on how to set Trustedhosts run the following command: winrm help config.`

My user is a local admin on both the client and server, and when I try to connect via HTTPS I get yet a different error:

`The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request. Verify that the service on the destination is running and is accepting requests.`

I've verified that the service is running on the server, but I don't see any errors in the Event Viewer log on the server. What am I missing here?

A couple of additional things noted during further troubleshooting: this is a SQL Server and as such does not have IIS configured or installed, would I need IIS to be configured or any specific features installed?

Also, if I specify the port (5985, as set up during the quickconfig), I get the following error:

`Winrs error:The server certificate on the destination computer (<ipaddress>) has the following errors: Encountered an internal error in the SSL library.`

Is this pointing towards not having IIS installed or configured?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the SQL Server doesn't have SSL certificates installed, so I can't use SSL. Instead, I use HTTP and made sure to mark the server as a Trusted Host on the client using the following setting (although a server IP instead of * would work).

`winrm set winrm/config/client @{TrustedHosts="*"}`